# How do I get Text Mining on Orange version 3.18

Tags: text-mining, orange

I just downloaded Orange version 3.18, but it is not displaying any of the Text Mining widgets (i.e. Corpus Viewer, Word count).

Is there a later version of Orange that I should download or is there a specific Add On I should download?

In Orange I have looked in "Options" and "Add-Ons" but there are no packages available to select.

Comment: Yes, you need to go to the Add-ons tab and then install the Text add on to get access to these features.